# JavaScript textbox new line replacement

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a text box that can allow the users to hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. When they hit <kbd>enter</kbd> I check the input and replace the carriage return with `\n`. However it still sends to my database a carriage return.
What could be wrong?

Here is the code:

```
var pp = comment.value;  
alert(pp.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "\n"));  
comment.value =  pp.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "\n");
```

and in my database I still get carriage return character even though I am replacing it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "save it"? Are you referring to a database, a file, client-side storage, or something completely different?

Comment: I mean client side..before sending it to db

Comment: What platform are you using? In Firefox 3.6.3/Linux, I already only see `\n` characters at the end of lines.

Comment: do you mean you want to manually set the characters between lines for a `textarea` element?

Comment: I've tested in a couple different browsers (including IE6 on WinXP), and I'm not getting any \r characters from a text box at all. You may have to do this on the server side. What kind of database/server are you running?

Comment: Regarding your update: what kind of database/server are you running? Many systems store a newline as `0D 0A`, so it's completely normal that there are carriage returns (`0D`) in your database. What's the trouble with those CR's being there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set an `onsubmit` handler on your form, you'll be able to change the contents of the textarea element before sending it. You can then use the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to change every `\r` to `\n`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Replace carriage returns in textarea</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form id="theForm">
   <textarea id="theTextarea" name="txtarea" rows=10 cols=50></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
  <script>
   function replace_newlines() {
     var textField = document.getElementById("theTextarea");
     var textString = textField.value;
     textField.value = textString.replace(/\r/g, "\n");
   }

   document.getElementById("theForm").onsubmit = replace_newlines;
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that does it in pure javascript, but it'd be much cleaner if you were using something like jquery.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id='txt'></textarea>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var txtarea = document.getElementById('txt');
    txtarea.onkeypress = keyHandler;
    function keyHandler(e){
        if (document.all) { e = window.event; }
        if (document.layers || e.which) { pressedKey = e.which; }
        if (document.all) { pressedKey = e.keyCode; }
        if(pressedKey == '13'){
            txtarea.value = this.value + '\\n';
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're testing for `document.all` and conclude that it's IE you're dealing with? That's the wrong way of browser detection. You'd rather use [feature detection](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/12/29/feature-detection-is-not-browser-detection/). Also, use `var` to declare your variables locally, as you'll overwrite an earlier declared `e` now: `var e = e || window.event;`, etc.

Comment: Since e is a parameter to the function, it's already "declared", and considered to be within the local scope of the function.

Comment: @Ryan: Correct, `e` is, but `pressedKey` isn't.

Comment: Indeed... missed that one :-)